# use of structure with one field only

Tags: c

I was studying about socket programming using C. In the header file netinet/in.h there is this code

```
struct in_addr
{
     in_addr_t s_addr;
};
```

and this structure is used in the following structure.

```
struct sockaddr_in
{
      short   sin_family; /* must be AF_INET */
      u_short sin_port;
      struct  in_addr sin_addr;
      char    sin_zero[8]; /* Not used, must be zero */
};
```

What could be the reason of creating in_addr structure, while they could have just used it as a normal variable?

Comment: abstraction there are quite a few variants of struct sockaddr_* and corresponding *_addr

Comment: Take a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979150/why-is-sin-addr-inside-the-structure-in-addr)

Answer (score 0):

Thats an abstraction layer. The rest of the code is written platform agnostic, and what exactly is in `struct in_addr` is presumably different on different platforms. This abstraction is done so the rest of the code *can be* platform agnostic.